# Suma en PHP decimales errónea

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un POS con PHP donde sumo valores del **precio** de un producto y su **porte**, para que me de un **precio total**. Cuando ingreso los datos con una ventana modal me hace la suma del **precio total** con dos decimales, que es lo que he programado. Pero cuando quiero editar/actualizar el **precio** o el **porte**, la suma total me la devuelve con una pila decimáles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando lo guardo tanto en base de datos como en la vista lo hace bien, solo muestra el error cuando hace la suma en la ventana modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la ventana modal del botón editar es el siguiente:

```html
<!-- 5 Editar Precio -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg editarPrecioPanel" name="editarPrecioPanel" id="editarPrecioPanel" min="0" step="any" required>
  </div>
</div>
    
<!-- 6 Editar Porte -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg editarPrecioPortePanel" name="editarPortePanel" id="editarPortePanel" min="0" step="any" required>
  </div>
</div>
    
<!-- 7 Editar Precio Total -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarPrecioTotalPanel" id="editarPrecioTotalPanel" min="0" step="any" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por otro lado el código de JS és el siguiente:

```javascript
    /*=============================================
    AGREGAR PRECIO DE VENTA
    =============================================*/
    
    $(".ingresarPrecio").change(function(){
    
        var porte = $(".precioPorte").val();
        
        var porcentaje = Number($("#nuevoPrecioPanel").val()) + Number(porte);
        
        $("#nuevoPrecioTotalPanel").val(porcentaje).toFixed(2);
        $("#nuevoPrecioTotalPanel").prop("readonly", true);
    
    })
    
    /*=============================================
    CAMBIO PORTE
    =============================================*/
    
    $(".precioPorte").change(function(){
    
        var porte = $(".precioPorte").val();
        
        var porcentaje = Number($("#nuevoPrecioPanel").val()) + Number(porte);
    
        
        $("#nuevoPrecioTotalPanel").val(porcentaje).toFixed(2);
        $("#nuevoPrecioTotalPanel").prop("readonly", true);
    
    })
        
    /*=============================================
    EDITAR PRECIO DE VENTA
    =============================================*/
     
    
    $(".editarPrecioPanel").change(function(){
    
        var porte = $(".editarPrecioPortePanel").val();
        
        var porcentaje = Number($("#editarPrecioPanel").val()) + Number(porte);
        
        $("#editarPrecioTotalPanel").val(porcentaje).toFixed(2);
        $("#editarPrecioTotalPanel").prop("readonly", true);
    
    })
    
    /*=============================================
    EDITAR PORTE
    =============================================*/
    
    $(".editarPrecioPortePanel").change(function(){
    
        var porte = $(".editarPrecioPortePanel").val();
        
        var porcentaje = Number($("#editarPrecioPanel").val()) + Number(porte);
    
        
        $("#editarPrecioTotalPanel").val(porcentaje).toFixed(2);
        $("#editarPrecioTotalPanel").prop("readonly", true);
    
    })
```

A ver si me podéis echar un cable porque no paro de darle vueltas y no encuentro el error.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En la ventana no estás haciendo el limitar la cantidad de decimales ??

Comment: Lo estoy limitando a dos, con .toFixed(2).

Comment: @Cristo Te equivocaste donde aplicar el `.toFixed(2)`. Si te fijas pusiste `val(porcentaje).toFixed(2);` y deberia ser `val(porcentaje.toFixed(2));` (_En 4 lugares tenes que hacer la misma modificación_)

Comment: Prueba lo mencionado arriba, y necesito un [mre] donde poder VER el error.

Answer (score 1):

Me ha funcionado a la perfección la [sugerencia de Marcos en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/524678/suma-en-php-decimales-err%c3%b3nea/524691#comment929163_524678), meter el `.toFixed(2)` dentro del paréntesis.